# Speeding up a query with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, performance, join, oracle11g, inner-join

I have a query that takes a long time to execute. I've waited for about 10 mins and it's still not finished executing.

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
  one.ID, 
  two.NAME, 
  two.STATUS, 
  four.KEY, 
  four.VALUE, 
  count(one.ID) as num
FROM TABLE_ONE one, TABLE_TWO two, TABLE_THREE three, TABLE_FOUR four
WHERE one.STATE='RED'
  AND (two.STATUS='ON' OR two.STATUS='OFF')
  AND (
    four.KEY='FINAL'
    OR four.KEY='LIMIT'
    OR (
      four.KEY='MODE'
      AND (
        four.VALUE='T'
        OR four.VALUE='R')))
GROUP BY one.ID, two.NAME, two.STATUS, four.KEY, four.VALUE
ORDER BY group_name ASC;
```

I have another query which is equivalent but executes very fast (about 1 second to execute).

Here is that query:

```
SELECT 
  one.ID, 
  two.NAME, 
  two.STATUS, 
  four.KEY, 
  four.VALUE, 
  count(one.ID) as num
FROM TABLE_ONE one
INNER JOIN TABLE_TWO two
ON one.ID=two.ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_THREE three
ON two.ID=three.GROUP_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_FOUR four
ON three.ID=four.ID
 WHERE one.STATE='RED'
  AND (two.STATUS='ON' OR two.STATUS='OFF')
  AND (
    four.KEY='FINAL'
    OR four.KEY='LIMIT'
    OR (
      four.KEY='MODE'
      AND (
        four.VALUE='T'
        OR four.VALUE='R')))
GROUP BY one.ID, two.NAME, two.STATUS, four.KEY, four.VALUE
ORDER BY group_name ASC;
```

I'm kind of confused why the query with `INNER JOIN` executes really fast (about 1 second) and the one without takes a long time (waited about 10mins and still not finised executing).

Is there anything I can do to the query without the `INNER JOIN` to speed up the execution time?

I am using ORACLE.

Comment: You should look at the execution plan (or "Explain Plan"). My guess is that the `inner join` version is using indexes to boost performance, whereas the version with the join criteria mixed together with filter criteria is for some reason NOT using indexes.  Or some other difference that should be obvious when you look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

In the first query, the tables are not really joined on any columns. The result is called [`cross join`](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php). Cross join between two table returns rows equals to number of rows in the first table times the numbers of rows in the second table.

`Inner join` joins based on given set of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your long running query has no join conditions to relate one table to the other.  Therefore it is creating a cartesian product of all the records in each table.  So if each table has 10 rows, it would generate 10*10*10*10=10,000 result rows before performing the aggregate functions.  Larger tables just get worse.  If each table had 1,000 rows you'd end up generating 1,000,000,000,000 rows.

Your faster query has join criteria which significantly reduces the number of rows in the result set, which is why it is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have N values for ID.  In the first query you will create N * N * N * N (or N ^ 4) rows.

In the second you will create N rows.

In big O notation:

```
O(N^4)
```

vs

```
O(N)
```

Now you have a real world example of the impact.